# Will two blades or three blades last longer on a hobby drone?

Tags: blade, battery

Will it be better to run a lighter 2 blade prop vs a heavier 3 blade prop for longevity and battery life? they are the same length. I am curious if the extra weight of the third blade will inhibit the time..

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more readable.  If this has changed the meaning feel free to roll back to the previous version.

Comment: A 2-blade prop should be better. Read [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/what-are-the-advantages-of-more-than-4-propeller-blades) about the efficiency of props and their blade count.