# Is a propeller with two long blades more efficient than one with three shorter blades?

Tags: propeller, efficiency

[image]

Is a longer, two-bladed propeller more efficient than a three-bladed propeller with a smaller diameter?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to clearly state what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Already answered here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/what-are-the-advantages-of-more-than-4-propeller-blades

Answer (score 1):

As Troy E and Dave said, most of this question is already answered [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/what-are-the-advantages-of-more-than-4-propeller-blades).

In addition to this previous answer, just remember that a propeller is a technological solution to a simple question: *how do we make the aircraft fly ?* Therefore, there is no single solution, but multiple compromises that can be found depending on various parameters, mostly based on the type of operations the aircraft should take part in :

- Speed
- Altitude
- Mass of the aircraft
- FOD / injestion risks and tolerance
- ...

Since your question only states the efficiency of the propeller, you actually miss at least part of the real problem. 
Let's say you manage to make a propeller with an efficiency of **1**, but that it weighs **1** ton or is impossible to manufacture, you won't get far.

In that sense, only considering the efficiency to say what is the *best* solution is not good enough. The best solution is the *best compromise between all of your requirements*, that's why it is so difficult to find ;) !

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a definitive source, but I read this recently:
"The rule of thumb is that you need 100 HP to justify each blade. Two blades are considered adequate through 200 HP. Three-bladed props seem to come into their own on efficiency at or above 300 HP. "