# Does a 3-blade prop handle up/down drafts better than a 2-blade?

Tags: experimental-aircraft, propeller-aircraft

I'm about to order a plane kit (RV-10) and one of the choices I'll be making is a 3-blade vs 2-blade propeller. A 3-blade prop should be: easier to balance, quieter and capable of generating more thrust - assuming engine has adequate power - which helps to shorten the take-off distance. However, it also adds more drag (i.e. it's less efficient) so it's common to see a reduction of top-speed.

Can anyone comment on their relative performance in winds or high density altitudes? I'm not concerned about the top-speed as much as dealing with adverse weather. I plan to fly in or near the Rockies. If benefits are negligible, the cost savings are considerable when going with a 2-blade prop. I reached out to Hartzell but have not heard back.

Comment: I think the answer can be found in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/what-are-the-advantages-of-more-than-4-propeller-blades) and in [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32234/why-are-three-bladed-helicopters-relatively-rare?r=SearchResults)

Comment: The benefit of the 3 blade is noise level and ground clearance. If those are critical features, spend the money.  For pure efficiency, a 2 blade will give more static thrust.  In the bush, Beaver and C-185 operators like 3 blade props because it eliminates the searing BLAAAT sound on takeoff from supersonic tips and reduces complaints by the neighbours.  If you can afford to build an RV-10 in the first place, the cost difference probably isn't a show stopper.

Comment: Seems like rate of climb and takeoff should be priorities (high DAs?).  I'd go with a three blade.  A few more knots in cruise out of a two blade really doesn't do much fore me.